Do two word bots need escaping with %20 or are spaces Ok in robots.txt
I want to tell Baidu not to crawl. One of their crawlers is Baidu Spider.
Should that be:
User-agent: Baidu%20Spider
or
User-agent: Baidu Spider

I can't find anything that says you can use %20, so I wouldn't. Checking my own robot.text it contains: User-agent: Baiduspider. Google says: Spaces are optional. In reality, I cannot find anything definite on how you should do it.

Yeah information is woefully sparse even on supposedly authoritative sites on the space issue.  FWIW there are sites I've seen that list known spiders and they include Baidu Spider, with a space.
My concern is mostly having robots.txt not read by, say, Google because of a syntax error (it's happened before albeit with an obvious 'whoops' mistake.
